# webaudio API: adjust play length of an audio sample (eg "C5.mp3")?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Can I use a (soundfont) sample e.g. "C5.mp3" and **extend or shorten its duration** for a given time (without distorting the pitch)?

(Would be great if this was as easy as using an oscillator and change the timings of **NoteOn and NoteOff**, but with a more **natural sound** rather than sine waves)? (Can that be done easily **without** having to resort to MIDI.js or similar?)

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to loop the mp3 or record a longer sample.  Looping can be tricky to make seamless without clicks or pops though, and depending on the sample you would hear the attack of the note each time it looped.

.mp3s and other formats of recorded audio are all finite, predetermined sets of binary data.  The reason it's so easy to manipulate sine waves with an oscillator is because the web audio api is dynamically generating the wave based on the input you're giving it.

Answer (score 0):

Good soundfonts have loop points for endless sounds. See example for WebAudioFont

https://surikov.github.io/webaudiofont/examples/flute.html